# Calling Stored Procedure from VB.NET without errors, but nothing happens in Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, adodb

I am experiencing a small problem with calling a stored procedure from VB.NET using the ADODB Library (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library).

I have the following stored procedure (copy from MySQL):

```
USE [DAB_Eindopdracht_DAB-TH]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAlterTypeVermogen] 

@strModel as varchar(30),
@strType as varchar(30),
@intVermogen as int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @inttblTypeID int
DECLARE @inttblModelID int
DECLARE @inttblModelTypeID int
SET @inttblTypeID = (SELECT ID FROM tblType WHERE strNaam = @strType)
SET @inttblModelID = (SELECT ID FROM tblModel WHERE strNaam = @strModel)
SET @inttblModelTypeID = (SELECT ID FROM tblModelType WHERE typeID = @inttblTypeID AND modelID = @inttblModelID)

-- Update QUERY
UPDATE tblModelType
SET intVermogen = @intVermogen
WHERE ID = @inttblModelTypeID
END
```

Then in my VB code I call this stored procedure using the following code:

```
Public Sub changeTypeVermogen(ByVal intVermogen As Int16, ByVal strType As String, ByVal strModel As String)
    Dim cmdData As New ADODB.Command

    cmdData.CommandText = "spAlterTypeVermogen"
    cmdData.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
    cmdData.Parameters.Append(cmdData.CreateParameter("strModel", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30))
    cmdData.Parameters.Append(cmdData.CreateParameter("strType", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30))
    cmdData.Parameters.Append(cmdData.CreateParameter("intVermogen", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput))

    connOpen()

    cmdData.ActiveConnection = cnnDatabase
    cmdData.Parameters(0).Value = strModel
    cmdData.Parameters(1).Value = strType
    cmdData.Parameters(2).Value = intVermogen
    cmdData.Execute()

    connClose()
end sub
```

Now my problem is that when I run this stored procedure from MySQL, it works absolutely fine, it does exactly what I want it to do.

But when I call this procedure from my VB application nothing happens...
It runs through my method, not generating ANY errors at all, but it doesn't change any data in my database either.
I have checked my variables for their values and they are in the actual database.... meaning that it should be able to fully finish the Query.

Is there anyone that could explain me why nothing happens? (and no errors come up).
Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?!

Comment: This looks like sql server but you state it is MySql. You need to first figure out which DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: My best guess as to why nothing is changing is because you don't have any rows that meet the criteria in your update statement. You could greatly simplify that update by using joins instead of multiple variables all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the @ in the parameter name

```
  cmdData.CreateParameter("@strModel".....
```